# Calc the sum of $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \sin(2k)$

Tags: summation

Solving a bigger problem about Fourier series I'm faced with this sum:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \sin(2k)$$

and I've no idea of how to approach this.

I've used Leibniz convergence criterium to verify that the sum should have a value, but I don't know how to calculate this value.

Comment: you can convert the sin into the exponential form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the series
\begin{align}
S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \, \sin(2n).
\end{align}

**Method 1**

---

Using the known Fourier series
\begin{align}
x = \frac{2 L}{\pi} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \, \sin\left( \frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)
\end{align}
it can quickly be seen that for $L = \pi$ and $x = 2$ the series becomes
\begin{align}
- 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \, \sin(2n).
\end{align}

**Method 2**

---

Using $2i \sin(2n) = e^{2in} - e^{-2in}$ then the series is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \, \sin(2n) &= \frac{1}{2i} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \left( e^{2in} - e^{-2in} \right) \\
&= - \frac{1}{2i} \left( \ln(1 + e^{2i}) - \ln(1 + e^{-2i}) \right) \\
&= - \frac{1}{2i} \, \ln\left(\frac{1 + e^{2i}}{1 + e^{-2i}} \right) 
= - \frac{1}{2i} \, \ln\left(\frac{e^{i} \, \cos(1)}{e^{-i} \, \cos(1)} \right) \\
&= - \frac{1}{2i} \ln(e^{2i}) = -1.
\end{align}

**Method 3**

---

As stated in the proposed problem the summation is given by
\begin{align}
S_{0} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \, \sin(2n),
\end{align}
for which 
\begin{align}
S_{0} &= \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \left\{ \frac{\sin(2n)}{n} \right\} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} \, \sin(2n) \\
&= -1 + \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \left\{ \frac{2 \cos(2n)}{1} \right\} \\
&= -1 + 2 = 1.  
\end{align}

Comment: How come you get -1 for method 1 and 2 and 1 for method 3?

Comment: @iveqy As stated in the proposed problem the summation index starts at zero. In method 1 and 2 the summation index starts at one.

Comment: Thanks for a good solution. Could you explain how you in method 2 do the step where $\sum$ disappears?

Comment: @iveqy  The series is transformed into a function, in this case the logarithm, by making use of the formula $\begin{align} \ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \, x^{n} \end{align}$.

Comment: You have an error in method 2, it's $\ln (1+e^{2i}) - \ln (1+e^{-2i})$, not $\ln (1+e^{2i}) - \ln (1-e^{-2i})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer fixed the sign error typos. thanks for the edit help

Comment: is it really allowed to do the $\ln a - \ln b = \ln a/b$ in  method 2 since it contains complex numbers?

Comment: @iveqy In general, you have - for any specific branch of the logarithm - only $\ln a - \ln b = \ln \frac{a}{b} + 2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$. Here, one can see that for the principal branch of the logarithm (which is the one you get from the series), you have $k = 0$ [since $\lvert \operatorname{Im}\ln (1+e^{\pm 2i})\rvert < \frac{\pi}{2}$, as $\operatorname{Re} (1+e^{\pm 2i}) > 0$]. But yes, strictly, that identity requires a justification.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$e^{2ik}-e^{-2ik}=2i\sin 2k$

Comment: And then use the formula for geometric series?

Comment: I think it's a tad more efficient to appeal to $\sin(2k)=\text{Im}(e^{2ik})$, since then there's only one geometric series to handle.

Comment: @iveqy Maybe I'm too blind, but I don't see any geometric series there.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Lets $\ds{\fermi\pars{x}\equiv
          \left\{\begin{array}{lcrcl}
                 {\sin\pars{2x} \over x} & \mbox{if} & x & \not= & 0
                 \\[1mm]
                 2 & \mbox{if} & x & = & 0
                 \end{array}\right.}$

> Note that $\ds{\fermi}$ is an *even* function of $\ds{x}$:
>   $\ds{\fermi\pars{-x}=\fermi\pars{x}\,,\ \forall\ x\in{\mathbb R}}$.

We'll use the
[$\large\mbox{Abel-Plana Formula}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula):

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\,{\sin\pars{2n} \over n}}
> =-2 + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\fermi\pars{n}
> \\[5mm]&=-2 + \bracks{\half\,\fermi\pars{0} + \ic\
> \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}%
> {\fermi\pars{\ic t} - \fermi\pars{-\ic t} \over 2\sinh\pars{\pi t}}\,\dd t}
> _{\ds{=\ \color{#c00000}{\large 0}}}}
> \\[5mm]&=-2 + \bracks{\half\times 2 + \ic\times 0} = \color{#66f}{\Large -1}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}\sin(2k)=\Im\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{2ik}=-\Im\log(1+e^{2i})=\color{red}{-1}.$$

Comment: what is −ℑ? And how come you get -1 and Leucippus 1?

Comment: @iveqy: $\Im$ is the imaginary part. My result and Leucippus' one differ because of the $k=0$ term, that is not included in my sum (since it looked not very well defined to me).